# How to enable drag after drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm not able to drag again after the draggable is dropped. Here is my code.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable( { revert: "invalid" } );
$( ".droppable" ).droppable( { accept: handleDrag, drop: handleDropEvent } );
function handleDrag(draggable){
   return true;
}
function handleDropEvent (event, ui) {
   ui.draggable.position({of: $(this),my: 'left top',at: 'left top'});  
}
```

When I drag again after drop in red box in my demo it should go back to it's original position . If dragged just out of the red box then also it should be dragged and set to it's original position.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tQnX7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom draggable `revert` function and if the element is not dropped on a droppable revert its position manually.

By manually I mean that you can store the element orignal position in a jQuery data (eg. `OrDraggable`) and then use it to retrieve the starting position of the element.

Code:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: handleRevert
});

$(".draggable").data("orDraggable",$(".draggable").offset());

$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
});

function handleRevert(e) {
    if (e === false) {
        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = $(this).data("orDraggable");
        return true
    }
}

function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.position({
        of: $(this),
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top'
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/SQL2v/

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to position at its original position, how to do? http://jsfiddle.net/SQL2v/2/

Comment: @NavinRauniyar It must be stored the original position, I'm checking it

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward You can do it by storing a `.offset()` in an outer-scope closure.